# Is there a way to find out that a user has opened a blocked popup in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, popup, window.open, blocked

I tried to use `setInterval` but new `window.open` object is `null` after being blocked and doesn't reassign after the user manually opens popup.

Comment: In my now-deleted answer, I suggested using code in the popup using `opener` to refer to the parent window. But then I tested it, and `opener` is `null` (at least in Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the notification from code in the popup window using local storage.

In the parent window a global scope (or use `window` instead of `this`):

```
this.addEventListener("storage", function() {
    // ...
});
```

In the child window, just set a `localStorage` property:

```
localStorage.here = Date.now();
```

That will trigger the `storage` event on the parent.

Of course, you don't know that they didn't just open the "child" window independently (since that's what manually opening the popup is), but...